# using a viewController to control a portion of the screen

Tags: uiviewcontroller

trying to implement a minesweep app. and ran into issues when trying to add the board to a scroll view for zooming and panning. and all touches were then sent to the scroll view only and touches were lost. 
i was thinking i could use another viewController to handle all the touch type events and pass off others (panning and zooming) to the rootviewController for the app. will i have to implement the difference of didStartPanning.

or could this be handled in the tileview it's self. and a  boardView
what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to confirm that you can't easily respond to touches for a sub view and a scrollview in the same view controller. it seems best to respond to view touches in the VC and use the scrollview at a higher level. it works great now.